# is it possible make a text color to inherit a its parent background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

I have a linear-gradient background; I am trying to make a text element color to "inherit" that linear-gradient background color while scrolling.

Look like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYK4x.jpg

*Note* Because it is linear-gradient background, set the Text color to constant is not ok.

Assume my code structure looks like this

```
<LinearGradient>
   <Text id="textA">Hello World</Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

I already tried give the `<Text>` a style

```
#textA {
   color: transparent;
   background-color: white;
}
```

However, because the background-color is under the color, setting the color to transparent would only become white

is it possible to do similar to the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYK4x.jpg by using pure css? If not, is there any ways to achieve that?

Thank

Comment: please try to give sample code with run

Comment: This is possible with an inline SVG.